# Why does DateTime.TryParse see "1,5" as valid (and how to prevent)?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

While trying to validate user input, an input string of "1,5" results in a valid date:

```cs
var s = "1,5";
DateTime d;

var b = DateTime.TryParse(s, 
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
          DateTimeStyles.None, 
          out d);

Console.WriteLine("s: " + s);
Console.WriteLine("b: " + b);
Console.WriteLine("d: " + d);
```

Output is:

```
s: 1,5
b: True
d: 1/5/2021 12:00:00 AM
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ua2O8x)

My intention was that "1,5" is *not* considered as a valid DateTime. Obviously, I'm wrong.

I've tried this both in .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET Core 5 with same results.

Having looked through the .NET sources of the [`DateTime.TryParse` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__), I still cannot figure out why this is considered a valid date.

In addition I would love to somehow prevent the method to recognize this as a valid date. My guess is to go with `DateTime.TryParseExact` but maybe there are better options.

##### My questions

1. Why does `DateTime.TryParse` in invariant culture consider "1,5" as a valid date.
2. How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: It's parsing it as "Month, Day" in the current year - that's why it allows it. `DateTime.TryParse()` is notoriously permissive - the advice is generally to use `DayTime.TryParseExact()` to avoid such things.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MatthewWatson, your comment should go into an answer, I guess 

Comment: @MatthewWatson is that documented somewhere? You perhaps could transform this comment into an answer

Comment: @cid I'll have a look. I confirmed that's what it's doing by changing to CurrentCulture and (in my locale, UK) that parses it as "Day, Month".

Comment: @cid Yes, this is a dupe question (Evk's sorted it tho)

Comment: Nice [mcve], though.  Complete repro in <10 lines of code.  I wish everyone did that!

Comment: If I would be _very_ picky, I would say that "1,5" (with a comma, not a dot) is _not_ a number in the invariant culture ("1.5" with a dot would be). So one _could_ say that mine is not a duplicate of the currently linked duplicate, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's parsing it as "Month, Day" in the current year - that's why it allows it.

`DateTime.TryParse()` is notoriously permissive - the advice is generally to use [`DayTime.TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0) to avoid such things (as you suggest yourself).

There's no better way to solve this than using `DateTime.TryParseExact()`.

This behaviour [is actually documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_DateTime__):

> This method tries to ignore unrecognized data, if possible, and fills
> in missing month, day, and year information with the current date.
> If s contains only a date and no time, this method assumes the time is 12:00 midnight

So it parses the month and day number, and then sets the year to the current date's year and the time to midnight.

Comment: Thank you very much, again. And sorry for posting a duplicate question.